# Axes formatting in R

Tags: r, plot, formatting, label, axes

I have a plot whose Y-axis is in the format "number.10^10". The Y axis thus plots the values like 1e+10, 2e+10, 3e+10.....10e+10. I would like to print it as 1, 2, 3....10 and I can always change write it in the label like "in  multiples of 10^10". I can't find a solution to this. 
For example

```
a=seq(1e+10,10e+10, by=1e+10)
b=seq(11e+10,20e+10, by=1e+10)
plot(a,b)
```

This is what a similar plot would look like, but I want to remove those X10^10 factor

[image: This is what a similar plot would look like, but I want to remove those X10^10 factor]

Comment: Maybe you want this: `plot(a / (10^10), b / (10^10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the answer here [R - Print ggplot y axis values in 10 thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798850/r-print-ggplot-y-axis-values-in-10-thousands/36799006#36799006), I would suggest:

```
a=seq(1e+10,10e+10, by=1e+10)
b=seq(11e+10,20e+10, by=1e+10)
plot(a / 1e10, b / 1e10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...this is the easiest way , which I would prefer

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
plot(a,b, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=a, labels=1:10)
```

You can suppress the original axis (x with `xaxt` or y with `yaxt`, and then use the `axis()` function to add your own labels at any location you wish

We can also specifically format the labels using `sprintf`. We generate the plot and suppress both x and y axes, then we add axes based on your data, with an integer format.

```
a=seq(1e+10,10e+10, by=1e+10)
b=seq(11e+10,20e+10, by=1e+10)

plot(a,b, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")

axis(1, at=a, labels=sprintf("%1.f", a/(1e+10)))
axis(2, at=b, labels=sprintf("%1.f", b/(1e+10)))
```

[image]

Comment: @AyanMitra I think you unselected this answer by mistake?